# run multiple threads in XPages

Tags: java, xpages

in an xpages app I am running java code to create files using apache poi. it turns out that between each run there need to be some interval.

I assume this has something to do with restrictions and perhaps multi-threading could make it possible to the same code in multiple threads.

I never done this so I wonder how I should set this up?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the XPagesExecutor Service. It is an internal used ThreadPool which is managed by the XPages Engine.

http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=2180

Multithreading is very powerful, but can be a mess, especially when using Domino objects.

Answer (score 2):

Xots has been very stable for me in production for some years. The latest release of ODA automatically passes all scopes, `facesContext` and `XSPContext` to a `XotsXspContext` object for you, if the Xots tasklet extends `AbstractXotsXspCallable` or `AbstractXotsXspRunnable`. It also allows logging to OpenLog using `XotsUtil.handleException(final Throwable t, final XotsContext xotsContext)`. A point on scopes, I would recommend using `requestScope` and `viewScope` only for read activities. But I've had no issues using multiple Xots tasks updating `sessionScope` variables. The various blog posts on the topic are on my blog http://www.intec.co.uk/tag/xots/.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is technically implied by the "some interval" bit, but there are a number of ways to do threading in an XPages app. Probably the best place to start is the "Threads and Jobs" sample posted a number of years ago, which should still be as relevant: https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Threads%20and%20Jobs